# undefined type behave different in JS

Tags: javascript

I was just trying this JS code -

```
if(a){
    console.log("a IS DEFINED")
} else {
    console.log("a IS UNDEFINED")
}
```

and I am getting error -

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

But when I add `var a` it prints `a IS UNDEFINED`

```
var a;
if(a){
    console.log("a IS DEFINED")
} else {
    console.log("a IS UNDEFINED")
}

// prints a IS UNDEFINED
```

Why it behaves differently where in both case `a` is `undefined`?

Comment: `if (typeof a !== 'undefined')`

Comment: it type is undefined in the both cases.

Comment: In first case, a is not defined but at the second instance a is declared but it carries undefined value.

If you put a=0 or a="", still it will give you "a IS UNDEFINED".

Hope i am clear enough.

Comment: Try it http://jsbin.com/UteTOQI/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is completely understandable: It's two different uses of the word "undefined."

There's a difference between an *undefined identifier* and the *value*, `undefined`.

When you do

```
if (a)
```

...you're trying to take the value of the identifier `a`. If you haven't defined that identifier **at all**, it's a `ReferenceError`. The JavaScript engine has no idea whatsoever what `a` is meant to be.

In contrast, this:

```
var a;
```

*defines* the identifier (as a variable) and gives it the initial value `undefined`. So then when you do

```
if (a)
```

...the JavaScript engine knows what you're talking about: It goes to the variable `a` and gets its value.

If for some reason you need to know if an identifier is defined and you don't want to catch the error, you're allowed to take the *type* of an undefined identifier:

```
if (typeof a === "undefined")
```

That works (without an error) even if `a` is completely undefined. However, it doesn't make any distinction between the two things (an undefined identifier, and a defined identifier with an `undefined` value).

---

Now, as if this weren't confusing enough, in "loose mode" JavaScript has a very strange behavior I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): If you *assign to* an undefined identifier (instead of trying to read its value), instead of giving a `ReferenceError`, it creates a new global variable. Thankfully, we now have ES5's "strict mode" which makes doing that the error it always should have been. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use:

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
    console.log('a IS UNDEFINED');
} else {
    console.log('a IS DEFINED');
}
```

A variable has the type of `undefined` if it hasn't a value or if it wasn't declared before.

Answer (score 0):

In short, when you don't declare a variable but using it inside your code, it gets a ReferenceError as the variable you are pointing to cannot be **referred**.But when you declare the variable but don't initialize it,then the value isn't **defined**.

Example :

**First Case :**

```
if(j){
    //do something
}
```

didn't declare **j**, but referring to it.So it'll give an undefined error because of not getting **j** as a **declared/known** variable.

**Second Case :**

```
var j;
if(j){
    //do something
}
```

Here **j==null** will be **true**, but if(j) will be equivalent to if(null) that is same as if(false), not because **j** is **null**. Rather because **j** is **undefined**.